# Jquery.ajax GET not ending parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I am creating a UI for a content production area on a company intranet. I created the middleware API in a previous project. This is my first time using RESTful methods (and I'm fairly new to Javascript and jquery in the first place)

When I call my debugging local api from the jquery.ajax the JSON object is not being passed properly on my GET method.

In the C# API

```
[ActionName("THING")]
        [HttpGet()]
        public string GetThing(object json)
        {
            GetData getData;
            if (json == null)
                return null;
            else if (json is string && (json as string).StartsWith("{"))
                getData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetData>(json as string);
            else
                return null; 
            ItemReturn retVAl = new ItemReturn();

[logic to use JSON]

return retVal;
```

in the web page

```
loadThings: function (thingNumber, showBool) {
                showBool = (showBool === true);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: '{ "GetData" : {"ThingNumber":"' + thingNumber + '","Show": ' + showBool + '}}',
                    url: "http://localhost:11422/api/THING/THING/GetThing",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                    success: function (result) {

[logic to display things]

}
```

I can hit my breakPoint in GetThing fine, have it all working, but I can't seem to figure out why the object (json) in my overload is coming in null. I know it's something in the javascript, my unit tests work fine and my JavaScript is getting me to my breakpoint in the method, I just need to overload JSON object to actually be passed in

**UPDATE**

It is on the api side. I changed the overload of GetThing from (object json) to ([FromUri()] object json). This fixed the immediate issue but it is currently just translating the JSON object into a blank object

++Note: I had to change my post method overload to [FromBody()] rather than [FromUri()], I am yet to update the DELETE method to see which one that uses

Comment: your `data` in the `ajax` request is a string. Change it to a js object. or use `JSON.stringify` and then parse it on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem no1, you can't do this with `GET`. Two options

1. Use POST
2. stringify and use GET

#### 1) So this is how you use POST

Fix your ajax request as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { "GetData" : {"ThingNumber": thingNumber ,"Show": showBool }}, // JS object not string
  url: "http://localhost:11422/api/THING/THING/GetThing",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Please read the `$.ajax` post documentation for instructions https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

#### 2) Use GET

```
var obj = JSON.stringify({ "GetData" : {"ThingNumber": thingNumber ,"Show": showBool }}),
    url = "http://localhost:11422/api/THING/THING/GetThing?json=" + encodeURIComponent(obj);

$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: url, // Here we encode the obj for server
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

If you use this method you must change your controller to get `json` parameter as `String` and then parse it to JSON using your library of choice. [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: ok I need to return data, this function seems to fit a GET and when I had it as POST it wasn't even connecting with my API, giving me a 500 error. Now that i have it as a Get my only issue is the data not working. I did change from a string to JSON.stringify({ "GetData" : {"ThingNumber": thingNumber ,"Show": showBool }}) per your previous advice but I don't understand why I have to use POST instead of GET. Especially since I have another POST function and only GET was working.

Comment: Everything except for the data being changed from a string and you changing form POST to GET looks the same, am I missing something? Is there no way to pass data to a GET function?

Comment: No you **cannot** pass data to a `GET` method as an object, `GET` can only send strings.

Comment: @davidp04 check out my edit I added the way to use GET as well. I still recommend you use `POST`, it seems a lot easier since the framework does the conversion for you. But if you want to stringify and parse manually, go ahead with `GET`, it still works

Comment: oh I see, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding in the ajax settings: `traditional:true,`?

Comment: I have not tried that (nor do I know what that setting is), but it seems that the issue was actually on the api side